# Combine two arrays to one dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have two array given:

```
let data = ["12 Mai 2021", "12 Mai 2021"]
let prices = [45.0, 50.0]
```

now I would like to transform these two into one Dictionary like this:

```
["12 Mai 2021":45.0, "12 Mai 2021":50.0]
```

It would be even better if the output could be:

```
[("12 Mai 2021",45.0),("12 Mai 2021",50.0)]
```

But I don't know if thats possible....
On this board I already stumbled across the "zip" solution, like this:

```
var dictionary = [String: Double]()
zip(data, prices).forEach { dictionary[$0] = $1 }
print(dictionary)
```

But this somehow just prints:

```
["12 Mai 2021": 50.0]
```

Someone knows a working solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `12 Mai 2021` is the same date. The second will overwrite the first.

Comment: In a dictionary, there is unicity of the key, that's why you have the "issue". `["12 Mai 2021":45.0, "12 Mai 2021":50.0]` can't exists.

Comment: `zip(data, prices).map({ ($0.0, $0.1) })` ?

Comment: Larne thank you so much that solves both problems!

Comment: @Larme The `map` after the `zip` is unneeded. `zip` already returns the same tuples that `map` is creating!

Comment: I would have used `Array'zip(data, prices))` after hindsight. But I wouldn't have kept thz Zip2Sequence, too "strange" for me.

Comment: `zip(data, prices).map { $0 }` will also convert it to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want this `Dictionary`:

> ```
> ["12 Mai 2021":45.0, "12 Mai 2021":50.0]
> ```

But that is impossible. Each key in a `Dictionary` must be unique. The key `"12 Mai 2021"` cannot be used twice.

Then you say you would prefer this “output”:

> ```
> [("12 Mai 2021",45.0),("12 Mai 2021",50.0)]
> ```

That is an array of pairs (2-tuples), and you can get that answer using `zip`:

```
let pairs = zip(data, prices).map { $0 }
// Type of pairs is [(String, Double)].
```

If you really want a `Dictionary`, then you have to decide what to do about duplicate keys. Maybe you want each date key to map to an *array* of the prices for that date. Here's one way to do that:

```
let d = Dictionary(zip(data, prices.map { [$0] })) { $0 + $1 }
// Result: ["12 Mai 2021": [45.0, 50.0]]
```

Here's what the code above does.

1. `prices.map { [$0] }` transforms `prices` from `[Double]` to `[[Double]]`, that is, into an array of arrays of `Double`, where each inner array contains just one price: `[[45.0], [50.0]]`.
2. `zip` combines the dates and the single-price arrays into pairs: `[("12 Mai 2021", [45.0]), ("12 Mai 2021", [50.0])]`.
3. The `Dictionary` initializer converts the array of pairs into a `[String: [Double]]`. When it finds duplicate keys, it combines the corresponding values using the closure `{ $0 + $1 }`. Here, `$0` and `$1` are each a `[Double]`, so the closure joins the arrays.

Comment: there is a missing closing bracket in your dictionary initializer. Another option is to pass `+` operator as the uniquingKeysWith parameter `Dictionary(zip(data, prices.map { [$0] }), uniquingKeysWith: +)`

Comment: I added the missing close paren. That's what happens when you don't copy and paste the code.